# Amazon EC2: PostgreSQL remote connection hangs

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up PostgreSQL remote connection on Ubuntu server.

I changed `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'` in  `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`

Then I added to postgre config file `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` lines

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5
host    all             all             all                     md5`

But when I'm trying to connect remote DB by `psql -U db_user -h host -d db_name` it hangs and show message

`psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "host_address" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

PgAdmin connection hangs as well

Comment: You'll have to run `pg_ctl reload` on the database server to reload the new configuration. Check with `netstat -a` on the database server to see if it is listening on the port you expect. Try to open a TCP connection from the client to the server on port 5432 (or whatever you configured) with `telnet` to see if it is a network problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue using amazon EC2 service

Solution: 
1) Go to security group for your server instance 
2) Edit inbound rules
3) Allow all traffic for your IP